# Constructing Lexicographically ordered priority queues in julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to make a priority queue with integer array keys, float array vals which are lexicographically sorted. While I can make the type I am having trouble constructing an object.

`PQ_type = Base.Collections.PriorityQueue{Vector{Int64}, Vector{Float64}, Base.Order.LexicographicOrdering}`

successfully creates the type

`Base.Collections.PriorityQueue{Array{Int64,1},Array{Float64,1},Base.Order.LexicographicOrdering}`

But if I try to construct an object the way I would in v0.3,
`PQ = Base.Collections.PriorityQueue{Vector{Int64}, Vector{Float64}, Base.Order.LexicographicOrdering}()`

I get a no method matching error with the suggestion:

`Closest candidates are:
  Base.Collections.PriorityQueue{K,V,O<:Base.Order.Ordering}(::Any, ::O<:Base.Order.Ordering)
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert{T}(::Type{T}, ::T)
  ...
 in call at essentials.jl:57`

1) How can I construct this type (I don't understand why the priority queue is asking for an ordering object as an argument)

2) Is there a way to construct an empty priority queue of this type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pq=Base.Collections.PriorityQueue(Int64,Int64,Base.Order.Lexicographic)
```

TBH, I just took a look at [the source](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/ordering.jl#L30) and found out about these `SomethingOrder`/`Something` symbols and thought the `Ordering` suffix you were using was extra.

I'd say there's a meta/type/function relationship, but don't know the details

Answer (score 1):

On v0.4.5, this seems to work:

```
pq = Base.Collections.PriorityQueue([1,2,3,4],[1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5],Base.Order.Lexicographic)
Base.Collections.PriorityQueue{Int64,Float64,Base.Order.LexicographicOrdering} with 4 entries:
  4 => 4.5
  2 => 2.5
  3 => 3.5
  1 => 1.5
```